Importing raster with full information from ArcGis REST Service (QGIS 3.36.3)
I have asked this question about this issue, but another problem came up.
I imported this layer from ArcGis REST services, but it's rendered as Singleband color data. This means that when I export it I lose information on layer categories.
I though about separating the categories through raster calculator, but since they're not actual categories, they don't appear in the raster calculator.
Does anyone have an idea about how to get this information?
I don't actually need all the categories, just the forest ones (in case simplification is needed)
This is how the saved file looks like:


I was just being stupid. The file is available for download here.
